# Relaxing non-affine equality constraints in convex optimization

Tags: convex-optimization, convexity, relaxation

Consider the convex function $f$. In section 4.2.1 in [these lecture notes](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Eryantibs/convexopt-F18/scribes/Lecture_4.pdf), the author writes:

> #### 4.2.1 Relaxing non-affine equality constraints
>
> For functions $g_i(x)$, $i \in \{1,\dots,d\}$ that are convex but not affine, we relax
> \begin{equation}
>     \begin{aligned}
>     \min
>     \quad & f(x), \\
>     \textrm{s.t.} \quad & {\color{blue}{g_i(x) = 0, \ i \in \{1,\dots,d\}}} \\
>                   \quad & Ax = b \\
>                   \quad & h_i(x) \leq 0
>     \end{aligned} \implies_{\!\!\!\text{relax}}
>     \begin{aligned}
>     \min
>     \quad & f(x), \\
>     \textrm{s.t.} \quad & {\color{blue}{g_i(x) \leq 0, \ i \in \{1,\dots,d\}}} \\
>                   \quad & Ax = b \\
>                   \quad & h_i(x) \leq 0
>     \end{aligned}
> \end{equation}
> as the original formulation is a non-convex problem (non-affine equalities are not convex). The relaxed formulation turns affine equalities into affine *inequalities*, so thus has more feasible points and is now convex.

I'm not sure why the author converted the constraint "$g_i(x) = 0, \ i \in \{1,\dots,d\}$" to "$g_i(x) \leq 0, \ i \in \{1,\dots,d\}$" rather than "$g_i(x) \geq 0, \ i \in \{1,\dots,d\}$", since both kinds of relaxations have the original constraint $g_i(x) = 0$ as a subset. One reason would be that the constraint $g_i(x) \leq 0$ is a convex subset of the epigraph of the convex functions $g_i(x)$. Therefore, $g_i(x) \leq 0$ defines a convex set, while $g_i(x) \geq 0$ may not. However, I'm not sure if this reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.

If $g(x)$ is a jointly convex function of $x$, then $g(x) \le 0$ is a convex constraint.  However, if, as stated, $g(x)$ is not affine, then except for some trivial cases, $g(x) \ge 0$ is a non-convex constraint.

That said, in general there is no particular reason why the relaxation of $g(x) = 0$ to $g(x) \le 0$  should be any good.  If the solution to the relaxed problem does not satisfy the original constraint, $g(x) = 0$, all that will have been accomplished is gaining the knowledge that the optimal objective value of the relaxed problem constitutes a lower bound for the optimal objective value of the original problem.

Comment: You mean "...some trivial cases, $g(x) \geq 0$...", and **not** "...some trivial cases, $g(x) \leq 0$..." right?

Comment: Yes. I just fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to refine my reasoning: Given a convex function $f : X \to \mathbb R$, where $X \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is a convex set, all of $f$'s sublevel sets, including the set $\{x \in X \mid f(x) \leq 0\}$, are convex. This is straightforward to prove: for $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, let $C_\alpha = \{x \in X \mid f(x) \leq \alpha\}$ and fix any $x_1,x_2 \in C_\alpha$, such that $f(x_1) \leq \alpha$ and $f(x_2) \leq \alpha$, and fix any $t \in [0,1]$. Then, because $f$ is convex, we have
\begin{align}
f(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2) &\leq tf(x_1) + (1-t)f(x_2) \\
&\leq t\alpha + (1-t)f(x_2) \\
&\leq t\alpha + (1-t)\alpha \\
&= \alpha
\end{align}
and so $tx_1 + (1-t)x_2 \in C_\alpha$. See section 3.1.6 in the book [*Convex Optimization*](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/) by Boyd and Vandenberghe for more information.

Moreover, if $f$ is a convex but not affine function, and if the sublevel set $\{x \in X \mid f(x) \leq 0\}$ is not empty, then its complement in $X$, which is $\{x \in X \mid f(x) > 0\}$, is a non-convex subset of $\mathbb R^n$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3481411/652310) for a sketch of a proof of this).

Comment: Convex but not affine is not equivalent to strictly convex.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone you are correct. Fixed this. If you see anything else, let me know.

Comment: @mhdadk, would you please, say what you mean by all of $f$'s sublevels set? Is it equal to subspace?

Comment: @A.Omidi the $\alpha$-sublevel set of $f$ is $C_\alpha = \{x \in X \mid f(x) \leq \alpha\}$. All of $f$’s sublevel sets is $C_\alpha$ for each $\alpha \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @mhdadk, thanks for clarification.